# Kibana Dashboard (ELK) user based (scritped/dynamic) dashboards

Tags: logstash, kibana, dashboard, elastic-stack

In my use case, we have a number of clients who would like to access a (personalised) Kibana dashboard (pre-made in kibana). However, we wouldn't like different clients to see other clients data (for obvious reasons!)

The problem is, kibana "saves" dashboards as a URL (i.e.):

hxxp://myserver:8080/#/dashboard/Dash-1?embed&_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,section:0,value:0),time:(from:now-2y,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!(),panels:!((col:1,id:UK-Log-Map,row:3,size_x:5,size_y:6,type:visualization),(col:1,id:Total-logs,row:1,size_x:12,size_y:2,type:visualization),(col:6,id:Logs-by-week,row:3,size_x:7,size_y:3,type:visualization),(col:6,id:Log-histogram,row:6,size_x:7,size_y:3,type:visualization)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'Name:Joe')),title:'Dash')

would represent a dashboard with 4 elements for "Joe" (filtered in the query - last part of URL).

Changing "joe" to any other client (i.e. "dave") would show their data, thus causing a security hole. What would be the best way to secure the data whilst providing the dashboards for each user?

I have full control over most of the tech used for this, so anything can be considered. I.e. libraries, proxies, RESTful services etc. This just needs a way forward!

Another user has tried to achieve this with encrypted URLs (js), but this seems a little hacky to me. There must be a cleaner way?